# Friend-of-a-friend (FOAF) support in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, semantic-web, foaf

Does Facebook support FOAF (friend-of-a-friend) networks?
I think it had a plugin foaf-generator earlier, but it's now deprecated.

Does FB Graph search use FOAF under the hood?

Answer (score 2):

[Matthew Rowe](http://www.matthew-rowe.com/) has done some research on FOAF, and has created a tool to extract your FOAF profile from your facebook. The latest version of it is [here](http://www.matthew-rowe.com/FoafGeneratorRedux/)

Comment: btw, if an answer solves the problem or doubt on your question, the standard procedure is to accept the answer clicking on the tick sign below the voting ;)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done Via an App (facebook Application)

If two users have authenticated your App they can view each others friends and friends friendlist

i.e

If UserA and UserB are friends, and UserB and userC are friends

And UserA, UserB and UserC have authenticated your App

UserA can see UserB's friends (i.e userC), UserA can also see UserC's friends (Even though UserC is not a friend of UserA, but is a friend of userB)

UserA will not be able to access UserC's friends if UserC have not authenticated the App.

Basic permission will work for this. The access token needs to be used when using the graph API

Query will look like this

file_get_content("http://graph.facebook.com/frienduserid?access_token=app_access_token")

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what I was looking for a way/API to convert FB friend network data into FOAF. Are you suggesting I should develop a FB app to access friend lists of each user and convert them into a FOAF network manually?